# Porcentagem de um valor sobre outro

Tags: php, matemática

Eu gostaria de mostrar quantos por cento representou uma venda sobre o valor total.

Por exemplo:

```
Valor total 100.
Produto 1 representou :10% do valor total
produto 2: 80%
Produto 3: 10%
```

Só que estou fazendo o calculo errado. Como isso pode funcionar?

```php
<?php 

$produto1 = [743, 10];
$produto2 = [670, 7];
$produto3 = [560, 3];
$vendas = $produto1[1] + $produto2[1] + $produto3[1];
$receita = $produto1[0] + $produto2[0] + $produto3[0];

echo "Em outubro eu fiz ". $vendas . " vendas. <br> Minha receita foi de ". $receita. " reais. <br> <br>";

echo ($produto1[0] * $receita / 100). "<br>";
echo ($produto2[0] * $receita / 100). "<br>";
echo ($produto3[0] * $receita / 100). "<br>";

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Os operadores estão invertidos. Para obter uma proporção você pega o valor parcial e **divide* pelo valor total. Já encontrará a proporção, e apenas multiplicará por 100 para indicar a proporção como um percentual já que a conta inicial usa base 1 e o percentual usa base 100:

```
<?php 
$produto1 = [743, 10];
$produto2 = [670, 7];
$produto3 = [560, 3];
$vendas = $produto1[1] + $produto2[1] + $produto3[1];
$receita = $produto1[0] + $produto2[0] + $produto3[0];
echo "Em outubro eu fiz ". $vendas . " vendas. <br> Minha receita foi de ". $receita. " reais. <br> <br>";
echo ($produto1[0] / $receita * 100). "<br>";
echo ($produto2[0] / $receita * 100). "<br>";
echo ($produto3[0] / $receita * 100). "<br>";
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/gLQpzq). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/jwiozcmu-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Math/Percent2.php).

Comment: Muito obrigado, salvou cara!